# Order by a column not included in a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my data set:

```
myID    MemberID      SourceID    Acuity    
1       5             3           2       
2       5             3           1       
3       5             3           2      
4       5             3           1
```

I need to return a data set for each distinct MemberID, SourceID and Acuity combination. But I need to order by myID.  I am inserting this into a different table and need the rows to get inserted in the proper order.  The expected result I want is this:

```
MemberID      SourceID    Acuity    
5             3           2       
5             3           1
```

The problem is that I can't order by myID unless it is included in the group by clause so what happens is the result is opposite because it orders by each column by default.  How can I get the intended result and order by myID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is ambiguous, because there is more than one row with different ids.  You can order by the minimum id, however:

```
select MemberID, SourceID, Acuity
from your_table
group by MemberID, SourceID, Acuity
order by min(myID)
```